# Unrecognized Tag 'repositores'

Tags: maven

upon doing a `mvn clean` I am greeted with an error

```
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'repositories' (position: START_TAG seen ...tp://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">\n\n    <repositories>... @6:19)  @ /Users/geronimo.sanpascual/.m2/settings.xml, line 6, column 19
```

Here's my m2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <url>https://artifactory.sample.test/sample/sample</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>mvnrepository</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>artifactoryuser</id>
            <username>user</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>

</settings>
```

I tried adding it to a `<profiles> </profiles` tag but still didnt work.

Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

--Added the whole POM file--

Comment: Please show us your whole `settings.xml` file.

Comment: What you are showing is only a partial settings.xml file.

Comment: Full POM added.

Comment: @JFMeier added full POM, thank you

Answer (score 2):

According to http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd you can't have a  `<repositories>` tag directly in `<settings>`, you should include it into a `<profile>` like that

```
<settings ...>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>some_profile_name</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>artifactory</id>
                    <url>https://artifactory.sample.test/sample/sample</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>mvnrepository</id>
                    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </releases>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

   ...

</settings>
```